# How to calculate average from a dropdown excluding the "N/A" values

Tags: javascript

Have a client that I have built a simple form for that does basic calculations.  There are 6 drop downs that all contain N/A, 1, 2, 3.  And at the end a overall average is calculated from these drop downs.  client is wanting to totally ignore any drop downs that contain N/A meaning if N/A is in 2 of the 6 drop downs then a average should only be calculated on 4 drop downs.   I am just lost on the logic or if statement needed to tell the total field to ignore a certain drop down field if user has selected N/A.
   Here is my code and is not working..Please suggest some ideas.

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript">
var aFieldNames = new Array();
aFieldNames["N/A"]=0;
aFieldNames["1"]=1;
aFieldNames["2"]=2;
aFieldNames["3"]=3;
var nCount = 0;
var nSum = 0;
event.value = 0;
for(i = 0; i < aFieldNames.length; i++)
{
if(this.getField(aFieldNames[i]).valueAsString != "N/A") 
{
nCount++;
nSum += parseFloat(this.getField(aFieldNames[i]).value);
}
}
if(nCount != 0) 
 {
event.getElementById("bpover").value = nSum / nCount;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value):">
 <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
  <option name="1">1</option>
   <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
  </select><br>
   <select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value):">
  <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
   <option name="1">1</option>
   <option name="2">2</option>
   <option name="3">3</option>
   </select><br>
    <select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value):">
   <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
   <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
     <select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value):">
   <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
    <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
    <select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value):">
   <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
   <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
     <option name="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
    <br>
   avg <input type="text" name="Average" ID="bpover" readonly>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is your code ??

Comment: code is now visible..

Comment: @DebasishChoudhury If an answer helped you, you should accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! @Shakti Phartiyal's answer has an explanation of the things that were wrong.

```js
function calcAvg(){
  //Get all elements with 'class="select"'
  var selects = document.getElementsByClassName("select");
  //Initialize vars
  var avg = 0;
  var count = 0;
  //Calculate average
  for(var i=0;i<selects.length;i++){
    if(selects[i].value!="N/A"){
      count++;
      avg+=Number(selects[i].value);
      //Alert for debugging purposes
      //alert(selects[i].value+" "+avg);
    }
  }
  avg=avg/count;
  //Output average
  document.getElementById("bpover").value=avg;
}
```

```html
<select class="select" name="Value[]" onChange="calcAvg();">
 <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
  <option name="1">1</option>
   <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
  </select><br>
   <select class="select" name="Value[]" onChange="calcAvg();">
  <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
   <option name="1">1</option>
   <option name="2">2</option>
   <option name="3">3</option>
   </select><br>
    <select class="select" name="Value[]" onChange="calcAvg();">
   <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
   <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
     <select class="select" name="Value[]" onChange="calcAvg();">
   <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
    <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
    <select class="select" name="Value[]" onChange="calcAvg();">
   <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
   <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
     <option name="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
    <br>
   avg <input type="text" name="Average" id="bpover" readonly>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Always glad to help. If this answer helped you, you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: [Accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) is an official process, not just verbal confirmation (although thanks for the thanks :P). To formally accept, and give up both reputation, click the check under the votes.

Comment: @DebasishChoudhury my heart was really happy when you accepted this answer in your mind. But my brain says that if you accept it , you should do it on stackoverflow and not in your mind... ;)

Comment: @Feathercrown the code you have given is perfact...i have now clicked the acceptance button.....i was new in this page so i didn't notice,now i have clicked..

Comment: @DebasishChoudhury It's fine, no one knows how to use a website the second they get there. :) If you need help with anything that's [not quite on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I might be able to help you in [my chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138629/feathercrowns-helpdesk) once you have 20 [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 3):

**First:**

In your statement:

```
<select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value):">
```

you are using a useless **:** instead use **;**.

**Second:**

- The approach should be loop through all the select boxes.
- Read the values of the select boxes not having N/A as values
- Calculate average by converting the got values to numbers using `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` .
- Display it

See the code below:

```html
<script>
function calculateAverage()
{
  var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('select')
  var nSum = 0;
  var nCount = 0;
  event.value = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<boxes.length;i++)
  {
   if(boxes[i].value != "N/A")
    {
     alert(boxes[i].value);
     nSum += parseFloat(boxes[i].value);
      nCount++;
    }
  }
  var avg = nSum/nCount;
  document.getElementById('bpover').value = avg;
}
</script>

<select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value);">
 <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
  <option name="1">1</option>
   <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
  </select><br>
   <select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value);">
  <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
   <option name="1">1</option>
   <option name="2">2</option>
   <option name="3">3</option>
   </select><br>
    <select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value);">
   <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
   <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
     <select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value);">
   <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
    <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
    <option name="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
    <select name="Value[]" onChange="alert(this.value);">
   <option name="N/A">N/A</option>
   <option name="1">1</option>
    <option name="2">2</option>
     <option name="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
    <br>
    <button onClick="calculateAverage()">
    Calculate
    </button>
    
   avg <input type="text" name="Average" ID="bpover" readonly>
```